# How can I compile and evaluate logical operators and operands specified on an object?

Tags: javascript, parsing, ecmascript-6, boolean-logic

Is there a compiler or an easy way I can compile and evaluate logical operators and operands specified on an object. This is to akin to mongodb [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) and [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operators. For example:

```
return {
  $or: [
    foo: [...],
    bar: [...]
  ]
}
```

When the compiler encounters `foo` it will call a corresponding function with the value provided for the same. The same goes for `bar`. It will then `logical OR` the results of the two operations. I want to handle `$and` and `$or` operators. I would do simple checks for such a simple example but I want to have the ability to nest the logical operators. A complex example:

```
return {
  $or: [
    { 
      $and: [
        { foo: [...] }, 
        { bar: [...] }
      ] 
    }, 
    { baz: [...] }, 
    () => m < n
  ]
}
```

Simplified definition of `foo`, `bar` and `baz`:

```
export const evalFoo = items => {
  return items.indexOf("foo") >= 0;
};

export const evalBar = items => {
  return items.indexOf("bar") >= 0;
};

export const evalBaz = items => {
  return items.indexOf("baz") >= 0;
};
```

**Sample data:**

**Set 1**

```
m = 4; n = 1; foo: ['foo', 'x']; bar: ['bar', 'y']; baz: ['baz', 'z']

RESULT = true; // because $and results to true.
```

**Set 2**

```
m = 4; n = 1; foo: ['x']; bar: ['y']; baz: ['x']

RESULT = false; // because m > n and $and results to false.
```

**Set 3**

```
m = 1; n = 3; foo: ['x']; bar: ['y']; baz: ['x']

RESULT = true; // because m < n.
```

**Set 4**

```
m = 3; n = 1; foo: ['x']; bar: ['bar']; baz: ['z']

RESULT = true; // because m > n, baz() is false and x and $and is false.
```

Comment: please add some data as well and the wanted result. which function do you call for the items of `foo` or `bar`? what is the content of the arrays?

Comment: No, there is no "compiler" or so for this. You can however easily implement this yourself by (recursively) enumerating the object and calling your functions when you encounter such a key. Have you tried something?

Comment: I have not yet tried something yet. Thought it would be better to ask for help before trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MutaiMwiti No, you're not re-inventing the wheel, or at least nothing as fundamental as a wheel. I doubt there's a library that does exactly what you want, and even if there was then asking for one is off-topic on StackOverflow. Please show us your attempt, the solution is rather simple recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take something like this, where you differentiate between `$and` and `$or` or the functions.

It works by taking an object with the keys for array methods like [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which acts like a logical and by testing the values in an object and return `true` if all items with their callbacks return a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. Analogous works [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), but there is only one item necessary which callback returns a truthy value.

The other object contains functions and allows to access them by using the key.

The first par checks if the parameter is a function and if so, it returns the result of the call.

Then the parameter gets a check and if [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), like `null` or if the value is not an object, the function terminates with `false`.

For taking a key/value pair a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) takes place with the first entry from the object.

If `key` is in the operator object, the value is taken as method for iterating the `value` and returned.

If `key` is in the functions object, then the function is called with `value` as parameter and returned.

Finally a `false` is returned, because no other check was true and the condition can not be resolved.

```js
function evaluate(object) {
    var operators = { $or: 'some', $and: 'every' },
        fns = {
            foo: items => items.indexOf("foo") >= 0,
            bar: items => items.indexOf("bar") >= 0,
            baz: items => items.indexOf("baz") >= 0
        },
        key,
        value;

    if (typeof object === 'function') return object();
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return false;

    [key, value] = Object.entries(object)[0];

    if (key in operators) return value[operators[key]](evaluate);
    if (key in fns) return fns[key](value);
    return false;
}

var m = 4,
    n = 1,
    object = {
        $or: [
            {
                $and: [
                    { foo: ['foo', 'x'] },
                    { bar: ['bar', 'y'] }
                ]
            },
            { baz: ['baz', 'z'] },
            () => m < n
        ]
    },
    result = evaluate(object);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: that answer works. Would you mind breaking it down?

Comment: Kindly explain this line: `if (key in operators) return value[operators[key]](evaluate);`.

Comment: it checks if the `key`, like `$or` is in the object `operators` and if it is `true`, then the array `value` is called with the `key` of `operators`, like `some` or `every` with a callback of the function `evaluate`. the nested objects are handed over to the function and the result `true`/`false` are taken for the quantifier.